# Google App Engine + Custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

I was trying to map a custom domain name to site I have created in Google App Engine. However, the custom domain is not getting applied to the site. Below are the steps that I have performed after checking Google Help Sites and stackoverflow answers.

**1. Created / Uploaded Google App Engine Site**

http://myGoogleSite.appspot.com/

**2. Purchased a domain name**

mydomain.com

**3. Created a CNAME Record with my domain name provider**

Name: www

Value: ghs.google.com

**4. Created a Google apps account**

https://www.google.com/a/mydomain.com

**5. Verified domain name in Google apps account**

**6. Enabled services for Google App Engine.**

Added site http://myGoogleSite.appspot.com/ (Created in Step 1)

**7. Google Admin Panel**

Settings > Select Google App Engine site

Added New Web Address

http://www.mydomain.com

> RESOLVED

The issue has been resolved without any other changes after a day. I think the CNAME entry which I had added in domain name server did get applied a day later. Though I had checked it through dnsstuff.com on the same day and they were reflected correctly.

Comment: The steps you outline look correct. Maybe there is an issue with your DNS settings. Are you able to trace your custom web address back to google?

Comment: When you go to www.mydomain.com in a browser, what do you see? Also when you run this command `dig www.mydomain.com` in a terminal, what result do you get? FYI: This would be aproximately 95% easier to help with if you told us what mydomain.com is.

Comment: The issue has been resolved without any other changes after a day. I think the CNAME entry which I had added in domain name server did get applied a day later. Though I had checked it through dnsstuff.com on the same day and they were reflected correctly.

Comment: This is out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been resolved without any other changes after a day. I think the CNAME entry which I had added in domain name server did get applied a day later. Though I had checked it through dnsstuff.com on the same day and they were reflected correctly

Answer (score 6):

If the CNAME www does not work when directed to ghs.google.com, try ghs.googlehosted.com instead.  It's what at least some of their docs say.

For a company that can pretty accurately sift through millions of pages for related data, their documentation on their own products sucks hard.