# Point your domain not use in google app engine (NOT Sub domain) so i want domain just alham.me

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-apps

This is my problem not change custom domain in google cloud apps engine
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hdUA.png

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your project was previously associated with another domain. In the [Google Cloud Platform docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/domain-mappings/), there are commands to help you [delete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/domain-mappings/delete) a domain mapping and [list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/domain-mappings/list) the ones you already have.

If this doesn`t work see this answers:
[error : domain is already mapped to a project in google cloud platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345759/error-domain-is-already-mapped-to-a-project-in-google-cloud-platform), [Google App Engine + Custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280542/google-app-engine-custom-domain?rq=1) and finally this Google Groups [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/xycWwRX2OiU) where one of the answers explains how to **override domain mappings**.

Comment: my domain empty in terminal google cloud platform or call gcloud

Comment: Have you looked at all the solutions proposed?