# Google App Engine - Static IP Address - Route Domain Name

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, dns

I am running a flask application on Google App Engine Standard.

I have **not** found a resource which states that Google App Engine provides a static IP address. I am trying to route my domain name, let's call it 'mydomain.com' to hit the google app engine endpoint, which Goole provides as something similar to https://my-appengine-name.appspot.com/

I have verified the domain with Google and selected it as a custom domain.

If https://my-appengine-name.appspot.com/ was a numerical IP address I could simply route my domain i.e. 'mydomain.com' to the numerical IP address in the A name record. However, as from what I understand app engine has dynamic IP addresses for APP engine and so this is not possible.

What are my options here to route 'mydomain.com' to Google's App Engine domain: 'https://myappenginename.appspot.com/
' then?

Comment: The answer depends on exactly what domain name you are creating DNS Resource Records for. If it is the root domain (example.com) then Google provides you with IP addresses. For subdomains, Google provides you with a CNAME record. The steps are documented. Example: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google App Engine + Custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280542/google-app-engine-custom-domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition of John comment, if you choose the root domain of your service (in the example, my own domain `gblaquiere.dev`, a list of IPs (and 1 CNAME) is provided and you have to update your registrar with them

[image]

If you absolutely want only one IP to register, you can create an [HTTPS Load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) in front of App Engine and create a [serverless NEG backend](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs)

Comment: Am I supposed to add all those IP addresses to my registrar. I went to all the IP addresses, none of them take me to my site. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you need to add all these lines to your registrer. How did you test the connexion?

Answer (score 0):

Although @guillaume posted correctly above I just wanted to reiterate the steps explicitly. Generally someone asking such a question is a newbie to GCloud and it helps to have explicit steps.
At the App engine dashboard click on settings.
[image: App Engine Menu]

From the settings, click on ADD Custom Domain
[image: Custom Domain Settings]

To add a domain you needed to verify your domain with Google already, either through adding a TXT record or another method offered by Google (if you haven't registered your domain with Google). This verification can happen almost immediately with Registrars like namecheap.com or name.com (as per my experience)
Then go back to this custom domains area in the Google App Engine console and you will be provided with a list of verified domain you can select to route to your App Engine.

Once you have done this Google will provide you with a series of A, AAAA and a CNAMe record which you will need to update at your Registrar, generally in the advanced DNS settings.

[image: A, AAAAA, CName]

[image: Update Records at Registrar]

This should definitely be sufficient. I think my struggle resulted due to a problem with my deployed app which I misdiagnosed as a problem with the DNS routing. Thanks for the previous responses which assisted me.